# Populating dynamic char array leads to overwrite

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following problem. I allocated a 2d dynamic array of chars in C. However when I try to populate this array with unique strings in each line, every entry overwrites the previous ones. Thus, I end up with an array that has only the last string in every raw. Can offer some insights? Thank you.

```
FILE *dictionary;
dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt","r");

if (dictionary == NULL)
{
    printf("can not open dictionary \n");
    return 1;
}
char line[512];
char** hashes;
hashes = malloc(250*512);

if(!hashes){
    printf("OUTOFMEMORY\n");
    return;
}

i=0;
char *salt;
salt = extract_salt(shd);
char* encrypted;
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), dictionary))
{
    //hashes[i] = calculate_hash(shd, line);
    encrypted = crypt(line, salt);
    printf("%s\n",encrypted );
    strcpy(hashes[i],encrypted );

    if(i>0)
        printf("%s, %s \n", hashes[i], hashes[i-1]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You allocate pointers; you don't initialize them, and you don't allocate space for the copies.  You're (un)lucky the program doesn't crash, I think.  (What does `hashes[i]` point at?  When did you initialize it?)

Comment: It is actually not a 2D array.

Comment: char hashes[250][512] should be ok

Comment: I initialize hashes with malloc(250*512) Is it not sufficient? I need each row to point to the encrypted variable within the while loop.

Comment: @purec the static allocation worked! can you please turn it to an answer?

Comment: I am modest, sorry.

Comment: If using malloc, then one allocation for pointers(250*sizeof(char*)) and in loop for each pointer(512)

Answer (score 0):

```
char** hashes;
```

this line declares a pointer to pointer to char not the two dimensional array.

you need to change your initialization to:

```
char** hashes;
hashes = malloc(250 * sizeof(*hashes));

if(!hashes){
    printf("OUTOFMEMORY\n");
    return;
}

for(size_t index = 0; index < 250; index++)
{
   hashes[index] = malloc(512);
   if(!hashes[index]){
       /* memory allocation error routines */
   }
}
```